# "justify" vs. "align" in the context of alignment

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

A function offers an option. The value of the option decides if elements in a column are aligned right, aligned left or centered. Is it OK to call this option `justify` or is only `align` correct?

Comment: 1. This may be off-topic. 2. In the applicable domain (word-processing), the terms are unambiguously defined. *Align* relates to one aspect: left or right. *Justify* relates to aligning both **at the same time**. 'Center' is relevant in *Justify' but not in *align*.

Comment: What about "justalign"?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Align is the correct term.

Think of *align* as a vertical invisible line running down the page. You can *align* the text left on that invisible line, right on that invisible line or have the text centered on that invisible line.

Justification is a lateral horizontal measurement based on one of two invisible vertical lines - left *and* right for justified text or left only for unjustified text.

Comment: To add to the above, align also allows you to vertically line up all matching characters eg a decimal point in a column of figures.  Whole number figures without a decimal component align to the left of the decimal, any numbers with a fractional component have the decimal part aligned to the right for however many places.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst the modern terminology seems to suggest `align` is the correct phrase, this seems to be a recent innovation.

Certainly I've always used `left justified` and `right justified` and `fully justified` in the typing/typesetting sense... it is only since I've been doing web-based work (noting that HTML/CSS uses `align`) that I've found myself using `align` even though I still think of `justifing` paragraphs.

By way of clarification, text within a paragraph is justified, whereas the paragraph is aligned with respect to the margins (etc).  In the accounting sense, the numbers are vertically aligned by the decimal points, whereas the currency symbol is usually left justified

Comment: I think you'll find those two terms *align* and *justify* were being used a long time before the web and html came into being!

Comment: I don't disagree @spiceyokooko - but they *used* to mean different things, whereas now they seem to amount to the same (or rather align seems to have usurped justify)... as per the accounting alignment observation

Comment: Aligning on decimal points and commas has nothing to do with text block alignment and was originally for tab settings only. They should not really be used when referring to text block alignment or justification.

Comment: @spiceyokooko - looking at your profile, I'll take your (expert) word on it... :-)

Answer (score 2):

The question “Is it OK to call this option *justify*  or is only *align* correct?” implies that an option name is sought.  Both of those words are verbs. Nouns often are more suitable for use as names than are verbs.  Noun forms of the words are *[justification](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/justification)*:

> (typography) The alignment of text to the left margin (left justification), the right margin (right justification), or both margins (full justification)

and *alignment*:

> proper or desirable coordination or relation of components ([1](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/alignment)) or
>   when two or more things are positioned in a straight line or parallel to each other ([2](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/alignment_1))

It appears that the Collins and Cambridge dictionaries just referenced don't yet recognize special typographical meanings of *alignment*.  Nevertheless, my recommendation is that you use one of the words *alignment*, *[positioning](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/positioning)*, or *[placement](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/placement#Noun)* as the name of the option.